# Set parameters in form inside script

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

I’m generating a table inside a script with all registered user of Keycloak. I want to implement a detail page for every single user, when I want to add the ID as a parameter for the detail page. I always get the error, that the ID must be a string.

My code is:

```
formName.setAttribute("action", "{{route('user-list-detail', {id: user.user.id} ) }}")
```

Do you know how the parameter has to be coded so that it works?

Thank you guys

Comment: Can you share `user` value?

Comment: I return the user object form my Keycloak Server to the view. Then in the script I handle it

```
const allUsers = {{{toJSON(showUsers)}}};

  //window.alert(allUsers[0].user.id)

  let filterActive = true;
  let filteredUsers = allUsers;
filteredUsers.forEach((user, i) => {
```

In this forEach loop I want to handle each user and set it into the table. When I alert user.user.id I get the right id, but I cannot set it into the action of the form.

Comment: quickfix: `user.id = String(user.id);` before `formName.setAttribute`

Comment: @AluanHaddad unfotunately this doesn't work. I get the following error: "route" view global error: Expected "id" to match "[^\/]+?", but got "". But when I alert the var, I get the right ID

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost at that point. If id is a number, `String(id)` will not be empty.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The ID is a uuid